# How do you make a FIFO array in C

Tags: c

I need an array with a limited size where I can push ints in. 
Once the array is full the last one in the array needs to go out so there is a new spot in front so I can keep adding data. How can you do this in C?

Comment: Just make a regular array and maintain two pointers to point first and last position in array. When you add an element add it at position of last pointer. When you remove element, remove it from front and increment first pointer

Answer (score 6):

this should be a reasonable implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct int_queue{
    int *arr;
    size_t size;
    int len;
    int first_elem;
};

void init_int_queue(struct int_queue *queue, size_t nelems)
{
    queue->arr = malloc(nelems*sizeof(int));
    queue->first_elem = 0;
    queue->len = 0;
    queue->size = nelems;
}

void destroy_int_queue(struct int_queue *queue)
{
    free(queue->arr);
}

void push_int(struct int_queue *queue, int new_val)
{
    queue->arr[(queue->first_elem + (queue->len)++) % queue->size] = new_val;
    if (queue->len > queue->size){
        queue->len--;
        queue->first_elem++;
        queue->first_elem %= queue->size;
    }
}

int get_int(struct int_queue *queue, int index)
{
    // note does not handle the case for index out of bounds
    // wraps around for overflow
    return queue->arr[(queue->first_elem + index) % queue->size];
}

void print_int_queue(struct int_queue *queue)
{
    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < queue->len; ++i){
        printf("%d", queue->arr[(queue->first_elem + i) % queue->size]);
        if(i < queue->len - 1)
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct int_queue queue;
    init_int_queue(&queue, 100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 150; ++i){
        push_int(&queue, i);
    }
    print_int_queue(&queue);
    destroy_int_queue(&queue);
    return 0;
}
```

Not extensively tested but it's simply wrapping around the array everytime a new element is added, keeping track of the first element shifting if the length exceeds the size.